# How to slide out a box to full box-content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm refreshing our friends-site with our blog. I thought it would be nice the make use of jQuery. But I want to do something I'm not sure how to do.

Lets say I want to display 400 characters from a blog-entry, if a blog contains more characters I want to display a link 'read more'. I then want to the div where the 400-char blog is in to slide out to so it fits the entire message.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you need: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html